# Solve the following equation: $\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}} - \sqrt x= 1$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, radicals

A past examination paper had the following question that I found interesting. I tried having a go at it but haven't come around with any solutions. How would one go about tackling it?

$$\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}} - \sqrt x = 1$$

I'm seeing a relation between $4x$, $16x$ and $64x$ so maybe the larger can be simplified to the smaller?

I do encourage you to working within an examination environment (thus not making use of anything other than pen and paper and possibly a calculator).

---

EDIT: My question had a missing $-\sqrt x$ at the end, sorry!

Comment: @JessePFrancis - Do take it in the case where one would be in the exam without the help of such widgets; what does the value imply? :-)

Comment: I know, just commented it as a useful point, to verify if someone manages to come up with something!

Comment: @JessePFrancis - Oh sorry haha, wasn't aware. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Did you write the question correctly?

Comment: @mickep - I missed out a $-\sqrt x$ in all of that, has been added. Sorry :-)

Comment: @Juxhin   Ack.  You gotta be careful

Comment: So now, the answer $x = \frac{1}{16}$ seems to fit nicely. Question is, how  to get to that point in the exam.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$$\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}}  = 1+ \sqrt x$$

Squaring
$$ \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}  = 1+ 2\sqrt x$$

Squaring
$$ \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}  = 1+ 4\sqrt x$$

Squaring
$$ \sqrt {64x + 5}  = 1+ 8\sqrt x$$

Squaring
$$ 5  = 1+ 16\sqrt x$$

Comment: There we go, makes alot more sense now! :-)

Comment: @Juxhin, just missing a $\sqrt x$ gave enough training for the brain!

Comment: If anything I honestly appreciate how perfectly balanced this question is - was genuinely fun. Thanks again

Comment: True that! When I saw the edit I was like, $\sqrt x$ just killed all the fun! The question does have a certain beauty worth admiring!

Answer (score 8):

This is a very intuitive approach based on the fact that I assume to be in the exam room with no computer and even no calculator.

If there is a simple root $\sqrt{64x+5}$ should reduce to a whole number and $x=\frac1{16}$ is obvious (since $9$ is the closest square to $5$). From here, we can go backward (verify that every time we get another square) and check that this is the solution.

Comment: That's another simpler way to look at it; how did you deduce that $\sqrt {64x+5}$ was a simple root?

Comment: I did not deduce it. I assumed that $\sqrt {64x+5}$ was a whole number and I went backward noticing that every time it was the case.

Comment: Oh alright that's a nice way to look at it

Comment: Ah, the *principle of well-stated questions* comes in handy a lot, especially in competition and high-school maths.

Comment: I guess that's what differentiates the great from the good..

Comment: No, I am just lazy and I assumed to be in the exam room with no computing device (even my phone calculator) !

Answer (score 6):

You get rid of the square roots by successive squarings and changes of side.

$$\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}} = 1,$$
$$\sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}} = -x+1,$$
$$\sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}} = x^2-6x+1,$$
$$\sqrt {64x + 5} = x^4-12x^3+38x^2-28x+1,$$
$$0=x^8-24x^7+220x^6-968x^5+2118x^4-2152x^3+860x^2-120x-4.$$

Using a polynomial solver, there are six real roots and a complex conjugate pair, with no apparent simple value.

**This makes the correctness of the problem statement rather dubious.**

Comment: Of course, one must check for extranneous solutions after solving.

Comment: @Soke Right, for example $x$ can't obviously be greater than one.

Comment: You're right Yves, the previous statement was incorrect. Has been updated, very sorry

Comment: @Juxhin: no problem, nobody's perfect. Solving the bogus problem by hand seems out of reach.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Touché

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}} - \sqrt x  & = 1\\
\sqrt {x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}}} & = 1+\sqrt{x}\\
x + \sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}} & = 1+x+2\sqrt{x}\\
\sqrt {4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}}} & = 1+2\sqrt{x}\\
4x + \sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}} & = 1+4x+4\sqrt{x}\\
\sqrt {16x + \sqrt {64x + 5}} & = 1+4\sqrt{x}\\
16x + \sqrt {64x + 5} & = 1+16x+8\sqrt{x}\\
 \sqrt {64x + 5} & = 1+8\sqrt{x}\\
64x + 5 & = 1+64x+16\sqrt{x}\\
16\sqrt{x} & = 4\\
x & =\frac{1}{16}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I can imagine is to square repeatedly and then use numerical methods to find roots of the resulting polynomial and then checking for extranneous answers from our squaring.

Comment: Same. The polynomial I got didn't factor nicely, though. I don't know how you'd solve it on an exam.

Comment: Hmm, I would end up getting; $x^4 + 4x^3 + 16x^2 + 64x + 5 = 1$ -- not sure if I did something incorrectly, I'll continue trying to factor it out. Do note that it's a 5 mark question in regards to a three hour exam which normally reflects how much time is *expected* to be allocated to the question

Comment: @Juxhin You should get a degree $8$ polynomial, which has no general formula for solution.

Comment: Oh woops, now I'm realising my mistake. The answer above give a HUGE polynomial which I'm pretty sure isn't something we ought to be given in an exam as polynomials are given up to the 4th degree (which is why I tried working within that constraint)

Comment: @Soke, won't work. Answer is [*one of the solutions*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+64x%2B5%3D%281%2Bx^4%2B38x^2-28x-12x^3%29^2), accompanied by another 7.

Comment: Even though it's a bit of a spoiler -- the answer in the answer sheet is $x = \frac{1}{16}$ if that may help.

Comment: My computer says the solution is $x\approx -0.02752$, and not $1/16$.

Comment: Which is what another online widget is returning too; however I'm sure there's a more intuitive way of tackling this question

Comment: $1/16$ gives $5/4$ on the left hand side, not one.

Comment: Indeed.. can confirm that.. this is odd

Comment: It's pretty cool though if you plug in $1/16$ how all those roots simplify to squares of rational numbers.

Comment: Guys, I accidently left a small part out, please check the updated question, there's another $-\sqrt x$

Comment: @JessePFrancis I know, hence "checking for extranneous solutions"

Comment: @Soke, and then the little villain ($\sqrt x$) creeps in and kills all the fun!

Answer (score 3):

With the extra $\sqrt x$ there, you just square both side and keep doing it, miraculously some terms cancel out :)

Comment: To be precise, move the square root term to RHS then square both side.